# How to ensure that web app in a container successfully bound to a port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running simple web application (node.js) in a docker container. Application listens on local port 5000 which is exposed on 8080 on host. I would like to run automatic tests which will run on host and will make HTTP requests to my application. The problem is that when I am starting application with `docker run` I don't know when application is ready (when it started to listen on 8080 port on host). I could use simple timeout which would be long enough to ensure container is started and application started listening for requests, but maybe there is a smarter way of doing this?

---

I am also using `docker-compose` and I was wondering how it knows that container is "ready to use"? Consider following docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  image: myapp:latest
  ports:
    - 8080:5000
  links:
    - postgres
postgres:
  image: postgres
```

I know that docker-compose starts containers in correct order, so in this example it will start postgres first and then web container. However postgres container, when started need some time to init and be ready to accept connections to database. So theoretically web container can be started before postgres container is ready to accept connections right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a common problem. I've always solved it by implementing a basic healthcheck and polling.  The healthcheck will depend on the service, but it will look something like this:

```
start_time = time.time()
while start_time + max_wait_time > time.time():
    if healthcheck():
        return
```

healthcheck should be something that does a real request to the service. For postgres that would be a SQL query. Since what you really care about is the webapp availability. I would do an HTTP request to an endpoint that hits the database. When the request succeeds with a 200 code, you know it's ready to go.

Comment: I do agree with that approach which complements my answer and add the requested intelligence I was mentioning. +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that the host port is not an issue: if you can specify, copy and run your test in a container, that "`test`" container" can [run with a `--link` directive mapping the `myapp` container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links).

In that case, `test` will contact `myapp` on port 5000 (always, even if `myapp` container never mapped 5000 to a port like 8080 on host: this is container to container communication: no host mapping required)

That way, you can design your container to *always* test on port 5000.

The only remaining hurdle is the synchronization one, where you need to detect that the container `myapp` is started, before running and linking your "`test`" container.
You can run your `test` container just after running the `myapp` one, but your `test` script needs to be intelligent enough and wait for `myapp` to be ready.

Comment: Yes I know I can link directly to myapp container. "but your test script needs to be intelligent enough and wait for myapp to be ready" - This is what I am asking about - how to make it intelligent enough? Let's say that we are not talking about testing, but about zero-downtime container update. I have to start new container and when it is ready then switch ports let's say. But I have to know when container is ready for switching...